# Is there any way to check if an std::function points to a member of a valid object?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind, c++14

Let me demonstrate what I mean.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
private:
    int number;
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        number = 0;
    }

    void printNumber()
    {
        std::cout << "number is " << number << std::endl;
        number++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> obj = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
    auto function = std::bind(&MyClass::printNumber, obj);

    function();

    // This deallocates the smart pointer.
    obj.reset();

    // This shouldn't work, since the object does not exist anymore.
    function();

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
number is 0
number is 1
```

If we were to call the function like we would normally, replacing "function()" with "obj->printNumber()", the output is:

```
number is 0
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Just like you would expect it to be.

So my question is if there is any way to make sure that we are unable to call the function when the object has been deallocated? This has nothing to do with using smart pointers, it works the same way with regular pointers.

Comment: No. There is also no way to verify that a pointer points to a valid object or function, or that an iterator is not invalidated.

Comment: `std::bind` does not produce a `std::function`.

Comment: Interesting reading / possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680680/binding-to-a-weak-ptr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to check if an `std::function points` to a member of a valid object?

`std::function` does not point to a "member of an object", it encapsulates a *Callable*. When you bind it with an object, you get another  callable object (of unspecified type actually), that can be stored in an `std::function`

> So my question is if there is any way to make sure that we are unable to call the function when the object has been deallocated?

No, there is no way. But as noted by ecatmur, since `std::bind` copies it's argument(s), you are fine in your example.

Comment: In this case, the function *does* own the object, because `std::bind` copies its arguments.

Comment: @ecatmur you're right about `std::bind`, I remove this note.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is valid.

`obj.reset()` does not deallocate the shared `MyClass` object, because a copy of the shared pointer `obj` exists within the bind-expression `function`.  This is because `std::bind` copies (or moves) its arguments, unless wrapped in `reference_wrapper` (e.g. by `std::ref`).

If you instrument or place a breakpoint on the destructor of `MyClass`, you will find it is not called until the end of `main`, when the local variable `function` is destructed.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/euyKucLU <- The same happens with regular pointers. In this case the destructor is called before the last call to printNumber().

Comment: @whoosy: It proves nothing. UB. No member access. Take your pick.

Comment: @whoosy in that case you're reading and writing freed memory, which has typically different (still undefined!) behavior to indirecting a reset smart pointer (or indirecting `nullptr`).  You'll notice there is no segmentation fault in this case, whether you use the bind-expression or call `obj->printNumber()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

"This has nothing to do with using smart pointers, it works the same way with regular pointers."
This statement is incorrect. obj->printNumber() with smart pointer fails not because object is destroyed, but because this particular instance of shared pointer `obj` does not point to a valid object anymore. If you try to do this with raw pointers:

```
MyClass *obj = new MyClass;
auto function = std::bind(&MyClass::printNumber, obj);

function();

delete obj;

// This will have UB
function();
```

you will get completely different situation (undefined behavior) of using an object after destruction and memory deallocation.

There is no way in C++ to validate that raw pointer points to a valid object. But what you can use is a `std::weak_ptr`. It will not work directly with `std::bind` so you may want to write a lambda or a simple wrapper, where you would check that object is still valid:

```
auto wrapper = []( std::weak_ptr<MyClass> wobj ) { auto obj = wobj.lock(); if( obj ) obj->printNumber(); };
auto function = std::bind( wrapper, std::weak_ptr<MyClass>( obj ) );
```