# std::bind with nullptr pointer

Tags: c++, stdbind

If I pass the `nullptr` to the `std::bind` function, how I check the validity of the `std::function`?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class A
{
    std::string si;
    public: 
    A(std::string s) : si(s) {}  
    
    int getData(std::string x) { 
        si += x;
        return si.size(); }
};

A* getA()
{
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    auto fun = std::bind(&A::getData, getA(), std::placeholders::_1);
    
    if (getA() == nullptr)
      std::cout << "nullptr";
    
    std::cout << "output : " << fun("str");
    
    return 0;
}
```

The above program throw the segmentation fault.

Comment: You can't, so don't pass nullptr.

Comment: `auto fun = std::bind(&A::getData, getA() ? getA() : throw "oops", std::placeholders::_1);`

Comment: At the very least, you're missing an `else`.

Comment: There is no `std::function` in your program.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me, of course you can't and why would you even want to?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785311/test-stdfunction-validity-after-bind-to-member-function) could be related.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access the bound parameters of the function object returned by `std::bind`.

You can check whether the pointer is null before binding it:

```
if(A* ptr = getA())
{
    auto fun = std::bind(&A::getData, ptr, std::placeholders::_1);
```

---

If you actually need a function object whose bound arguments can be accessed from the outside, then you need to write a named function object type. For example:

```
struct Fun {
    A* ptr;
    int operator()(const std::string& x) {
        return ptr->getData(x);
    }
};

auto fun = Fun{ .ptr = getA() };
if (fun.ptr)
    // is "valid"
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> auto fun = std::bind(&A::getData, getA(), std::placeholders::_1);
> ```

You're binding the instance of `A` in the function object to a `nullptr`. Hence the segmentation fault. You should pass the address of a valid instance of `A` (for the second parameter) that is going to outlive the invocation of this function object you create.

There's no way to check the function object is valid retrospectively. That is, before creating it you have to check that the pointer is valid.

Something like this makes more sense:

```
A a("hello");
auto fun = std::bind(&A::getData, &a, std::placeholders::_1);
```

or

```
A* ptr = getA();
if (ptr)
{
    auto fun = std::bind(&A::getData, ptr, std::placeholders::_1);
    ...
}
```

Nowadays, lambdas have superseded `std::bind` to create function objects. The equivalent lambda for what you're doing is:

```
auto fun = [a](std::string str) { return a->getData(str); }
```

Now using a `nullptr` for `a` makes no sense.